# Flutter) How can I capture widget as jpg file not png?

Tags: flutter, widget, jpeg, screenshot, capture

I want to take screenshot as jpg file not png.

```dart
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

I know that using RenderRepaintBoundary is one way to capture widget. But I want to take it as jpg file not png file, because its file size. To upload image to the server, the smaller file size is, the better.

So, how can I take screenshot as **jpg** not png?

Comment: But you are providing .png format

Comment: It should generate png file as image